# Finding and Replacing String and characters around it

Tags: php, html

StackOverflow.

Let's say I have this variable:

```
$paragraph = "This is a bunch of random information. Here is a URL: http://example.com/inventory/personid Thanks for checking it out!";
```

I need to detect if the $paragraph has a URL in it, even if the `personid` changes, and then save it as a variable, then replace it with some new code. For example, this is what I should walk away with:

```
$url = "http://example.com/inventory/personid";
$replace = "newinformation!";
$newparagraph = "This is a bunch of random information. Here is a URL: newinformation! Thanks for checking it out!";
```

I'm pretty sure this has to do with strpos(), but I have no idea past that.

Edit: personid would be represented as something along the lines of `#730_2_1697061248` but the numbers would change.

Comment: 1. Have you tried something ? 2. *even if the /personid changes,* Means it should be dynamic and it could be any random id, correct?!

Comment: I have tried something with strpos(), but I couldn't wrap my head around it. And yes, I wasn't very clear. personid could be represented by something similar to this: #730_2_1697061248 but the numbers will change. I've added an edit to the question to address this.

Comment: Add ^ your attempt to your question, even if it didn't worked! Show your work!

Comment: So where are we with the question?

Comment: @Rizier123 Your solution has worked, I was so excited I forgot to come and tell you! Thank you very much. I can't upvote your answer until I have 15 rep, but once I do I'll be sure to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), like this to replace the url:

```
echo $newparagraph = preg_replace("/\b" . preg_quote($url, "/") . "\S*/", $replace, $paragraph);
```

output:

```
This is a bunch of random information. Here is a URL: newinformation! Thanks for checking it out!
```

regex explanation:

```
/\b . preg_quote($url, "/") . \S*
```

- **\b** assert position at a word boundary (^\w|\w$|\W\w|\w\W)
  test matches the characters test literally (case sensitive)
- preg_quote($url, "/") -> `http\:\/\/example\.com\/inventory\/`
- **\S*** match any non-white space character [^\r\n\t\f ]

  - Quantifier: ***** Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]